# BLE central ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy, arraybuffer

Using cordova BLE central with Ionic, I'm trying to write (withoutResponse).

According to the doc the data format is an ArrayBuffer.

From packet analysis I know that the written value should be `02FD 1600 0000 0000 002E 1481 1F8F 7500 0000 004D`

My question is how to create the required ArrayBuffer using JavaScript ?

I've tried with

`Buffer.from("02FD 1600 0000 0000 002E 1481 1F8F 7500 0000 004D").buffer`

But when I check the exchanged packet, the written value is

`3032 4644 2031 3630 3020 3030 3030 2030 3030 3020 3030 3245 2031 3438 3120 3146 3846 2037 3530 3020 3030 3030 2030 3034 44`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_buffer

> This ArrayBuffer is not guaranteed to correspond exactly to the
>   original Buffer. See the notes on buf.byteOffset for details.

Buffer's data in the underlying ArrayBuffer begins at `.byteOffset`

You are also using the wrong format for the hex string that Buffer.from reads, and you also need to tell it to use 'hex' encoding (default is 'utf-8').  It does not understand spaces (nor the concept of 16-bit values, which would be the job of TypedArrays and the .readInt16BE and other utility functions).

```
buf=Buffer.from("02FD160000000000002E14811F8F75000000004D",'hex')
data=buf.buffer.slice(buf.byteOffset,buf.byteOffset+buf.length)
```

I don't know where you got that data, but it looks like 16-bit values.  You will have to make sure of the endian-ness of the data, to make sure the bytes don't need to be swapped.

Get ArrayBuffer by using TypedArray.  This works in browser:

```js
    data = new Uint16Array("02FD 1600 0000 0000 002E 1481 1F8F 7500 0000 004D"
     .split(' ').map(x=>parseInt(x,16)))
    
    console.log([...data].map(x=>x.toString(16).padStart(4,'0')).join(''))
    
    buf = data.buffer; //ArrayBuffer
```

Comment: Hi user120242, if I had instead to create a buffer instead of ArrayBuffer, I would do it via Buffer.from("02FD160000000000002E14811F8F75000000004D",'hex') ?

Comment: read here: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html  but yes, that's one way.